# Solving a system of equations with 5 unknowns using only Gauss-Jordan Elimination in RREF.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm presented with this problem. Do I have to turn $x$<sub>3</sub> and $x$<sub>5</sub> into free variables? What would be the most efficient solution to this using strictly only Gauss-Jordan Elimination in RREF.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to label the points in the traffic as A, B, C, D. Since the total traffic in is the same as the total traffic out, and therefore the traffic into each of the points is the same as the traffic out, we deduce the following system of equations:

$$\begin{align}
x_1 - x_2 &= 400 \\
x_1 + x_3 - x_4 &= 600 \\
x_4 + x_5 &= 100 \\
x_2 + x_3 + x_5 &= 300
\end{align}
$$

Skipping the in between steps (do these for practice), the RREF for the augmented matrix becomes:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 700\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 300\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 100\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}

From here, the solution set becomes:
\begin{align}
x_1 &= 700 - x_3 - x_5 \\
x_2 &= 300 - x_3 - x_5 \\
x_4 &= 100 - x_5 \\
\end{align}

$x_3, x_5$ are free variables.

Now substitute the values:
$$x_3 = 0, x_5 = 10$$
to get:
\begin{align}
x_1 &= 700 - 10 = 690 \\
x_2 &= 300 - 10 = 290 \\
x_3 &= 0 \\
x_4 &= 100 - 10 = 90 \\
x_5 & =10 \\
\end{align}

And you are done.